# Cannot produce a background image in a panel in Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I was under the impression that 'backgroundIamge' is supposed to be supported in .setStyleAttribute to allow the user to set a background image in a panel via something like this:

`setStyleAttribute("backgroundImage","url('myImageUrl')");`

However, when I try the following:

```
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel')
  .setStyleAttribute('text-align', 'center')
  .setStyleAttribute('zIndex', '3')
  .setStyleAttribute('position', 'fixed')
  .setStyleAttribute('left', 10)
  .setStyleAttribute('top', 10)
  .setWidth(250)
  .setHeight(150)
  .setStyleAttribute('backgroundImage',"url('https://myImage.png')");
```

I cannot produce a background image in the panel. The funny thing is the exact same code will produce a background image in a button. I have tried 'background' and 'background-image' as well to no avail. Is 'backgroundImage' NOT supported for panels or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...you need to use createAbsolutePanel or add an empty label to other types of panels.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?  This seems interesting but your answer gives not enough details on how you solved it... thanks in advance.